# How to save a File to any specific path in Android

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I can create file. It's creating on /data/data/com.mypackage.app/files/myfile.txt. But i want to create on Internal Storage/Android/data/com.mypackage.app/files/myfiles.txt location. How can i do this?

Codes:

```
public void createFile()  {

    File path  = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath());
    String fileName = "myfile.txt";
    String value = "example value";

    File output = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(output.getAbsolutePath());
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write(value);
        outputWriter.close();
        //display file saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

UPDATE :

I fixed the problem. Maybe someones to helps. Only changing this line.

```
File output = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null),"myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the root directory:

```
File path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Instead of `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` you can as well use `null` or `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, `DIRECTORY_PODCASTS`, `DIRECTORY_RINGTONES`, `DIRECTORY_ALARMS`, `DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS`, `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, or `DIRECTORY_MOVIES`.

See more here:

- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. It's work.I founded solution. Your solution too worked i tried. I updated to question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer is helpful and I will add-on little guide on it.